# Thread-safe iteration explanation

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a question about the `Collection.synchronizedXXX` methods, who return synchronized views of the underlying collections.

Using these, **we have to manually synchronize the iteration** (e.g. [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List))), otherwise it may result in non-deterministic behavior.

*What does it really mean?*

I've found another sentence [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/wrapper.html):

> In the face of concurrent access, it is imperative that the user manually synchronize on the returned collection when iterating over it. The reason is that iteration is accomplished via multiple calls into the collection, which must be composed into a single atomic operation.

This is where I'm stuck. I thought that if I wanted to modify the collection I'd get a `ConcurrentModificationException`. So I need to synchronize in order to avoid getting this exception (e.g. when iteration is "paused" because of context switching done by the compiler).

The second link hopefully confirms my thought. How about the "non-deterministic behaviour" sentence? Does it reflect on the same thought (iteration pause) or is there something new behind the scenes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iteration is a long-running operation. The logic added by `Collection.synchronizedXXX` will see each `next()` call on the `Iterator` as individual calls, which will be `synchronized`, but you need to ensure that collection is not modified until you're entirely done iterating. That is why you have to add `synchronized` block yourself around the entire iteration process.

The `ConcurrentModificationException`, e.g. as thrown by [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html), is not guaranteed to be thrown:

> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast iterators throw `ConcurrentModificationException` on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: *the fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs*.

Comment: I'm close to the goal. So all I need to understand is that fail-fast does not always work well - does not guarantee anything O.o 

Could you tell me such an example when it does not realize that the collection has changed, please? It would be calming.

Comment: could you answer, please?

Comment: @Törpetestű No, because I don't have an example. Can't you just accept what the documentation says: It doesn't *guarantee* that the "fail-fast" behavior will trigger. Doesn't necessarily mean that it won't, just that you cannot *rely* on it. So don't expect `ConcurrentModificationException` to save you from unprotected multi-threaded use of a collection. If you intend to do multi-threaded access, use a **concurrent** collection, since that's what they are for. It's really that simple.

Answer (score 1):

Iteration consists in doing the following (directly, or indirectly using a foreach loop):

```
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    iterator.next();
}
```

So, if there is a context switch between the call to hasNext() and the call to next(), and the other thread removes elements from the collection, you end up with unpredictible behavior: the iterator told you there was a next element, and there actually is not. Instead of iterating on a consistent snapshot of the list, you're iterating on a moving target, with exceptions that would never happen on a list that isn't shared between threads.